# Mint, install and LUKS/LVM

Tags: linux, linux-mint, encryption, luks, disk-encryption

I want to make my linux laptopwith LUKS Encryption. OS : Mint 17.

Is it better to make the disk LUKS-encrypted:

- at the installation process ?
- after it ?

Comment: Is -1 due to question formulation or else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation, the installer will show you an option to encrypt the disk with LUKS.

Comment: this one I guess: https://cyberraiden.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/linux-mint-17-mate-screenshot-install-2.png ?

Comment: Yes, that one. Choose to use the whole disk for the installation of Linux Mint only if you don't have other OSes on your system or if you want to get rid of them.